# Can anyone find this anime/cartoon?

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

I remember watching this while I was somewhere between 5-10 years old, and I've been trying to find it again ever since. I can give you a very bad description of it that might sound like a lot of others.

What I remember of it is that a girl is taken from her world to another by a necklace-type thing like in Inuyasha, there is this boy who I think is a prince with a – I want to say – white dragon robot and a cat girl with him, the boy might be a prince but he also has a pair of wings that he keeps hidden from everyone.

Comment: You should edit the title to attract more attention to the question. Also, the description is not well worded.

Comment: Hello aika, welcome to [scifi.se] and thank you for your question. You may want to [edit your question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/158273/edit) to touch it up a bit; it could do with some capitalisation, for instance, or a more descriptive title. Also, _when_ did you watch it? We don't know when you were a kid. Have you taken the [tour] yet?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a quick Google search for "White Dragon Robot", I believe what you're looking for is [The Vision of Escaflowne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Vision_of_Escaflowne).

> The series follows a teenage high school girl named Hitomi, who finds herself pulled from Earth to the planet Gaea when a boy named Van appears on the high school track while battling a dragon. In Gaea, she is caught in the middle of a war as the Zaibach Empire attempts to take over Gaea. Van (King of Fanelia), with aid from Allen (an Asturian Knight), commands his mystical mech Escaflowne in the struggle to stop the Zaibach Empire. Hitomi's fortune telling powers blossom in Gaea as she becomes the key to awakening Escaflowne and to stopping Zaibach's plans.